# Is DynamoDB susceptible to NoSQL or SQL injection attacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, escaping, boto3

Do I have to sanitize user supplied input before I query DynamoDB or does DynamoDB handle sanitization itself ? (or through it's respective SDKs like through boto3)

As an example, this is possible in MongoDB (also a NoSQL database)

```
function() { return obj.credits—obj.debits < 0;var date=new Date(); do{curDate = new Date();}while(curDate-date<10000); }
```

---

I already found some techniques used here:

- [cloud.hacktricks.xyz](https://cloud.hacktricks.xyz/pentesting-cloud/aws-security/aws-services/aws-dynamodb-enum)
- [DynamoDB Injection (Medium)](https://medium.com/appsecengineer/dynamodb-injection-1db99c2454ac)
- [SQL Injection through PartiQL](https://ine.com/blog/dynamodb-sql-injection)

Comment: MySQL (and any SQL implementation) only have SQL injection vulnerabilities if you concatenate values into a query string. Not if you use parameters like you should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what are you trying to guard against? Strings are limited to 400kb limit, from a DDB perspective that's all to worry about.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html

DynamoDB does not execute code with user defined functions or anything so there's no risk of injection threats to execute server side code.

Comment: This post implies that there can be injection style attacks: https://medium.com/appsecengineer/dynamodb-injection-1db99c2454ac

Anyway the question is closed, so I've re-asked, more focused.